# Reading file from a specific line number in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have a very large file in which hexadecimal addresses are printed(one at each line). Now i want to read the file many times but each time i want that reading starts from a specific line number not from start. So is there any command in c++ which can do this. As the file is very large i can't afford to read it from start every time.

Comment: How large are we talking about?

Comment: Hitting Google with "c++ stream seek to line" gives loads of results...

Comment: Does each line have the same number of characters? That would help quite a lot.

Comment: yes each line have same number of characters..

Answer (score 1):

There is an [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) function in C and seekg in C++ that allows you to move to a certain destination in a file. Making it go to a specific line might take some thought on your end though. [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: even if each line has same characters does there is any possibility that the fseek function does not go to particular line. I am having this trouble and for certain range of lines it goes on correct line but after that range it goes to incorrect line...